# How get X509 certificate's full cert chain programatically?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, java, validation

Imagine I have p12 container of private key and public certificate. When I export p12 public cert to separate .cer file with Java keytool I may click to .cer file and see full cert chain. How may I get that full path programatically?

I made little investigation. I used keytool's `print cert -v` command and saw property   `AuthorityInfoAccess` with subproperty

```
accessMethod: caIssuers
accessLocation: URIName: http://.../some.crt
```

I downloaded that some.crt (it was PEM cert), and again used `print cert -v` and again saw
`accessLocation: URIName: http://.../some2.crt` and repeated downloading .crt files and geting parent until reaching root .crt which hasn't such property.

I think, that I should programatically download chain as I described above and provide it to `CertPathValidator` as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html).

**If I really need to get chain as I described above, is there any libraries already doing this? Is there any way to do it with std lib**? I didn't find bouncycastle examples and java's standart library code like

`java.security.cert.Certificate[] cchain = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);`

returns one entry for certificate actually having 2 "parents".

Comment: Please narrow your post down to a single question.

Comment: @DeerHunter, I eliminated some questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitpick: you surely mean `keytool -printcert` (with hyphen, without space, `-v` not needed here).

A privatekey entry created by Java in JKS or PKCS12 usually contains the full chain, but `keytool -exportcert` extracts *only* the leaf cert.
A PKCS12 created by something else may contain the full chain or not, possibly depending on what you clicked when creating it. 
*If* the chain is there, `KeyStore.getCertificateChain` returns it, and `keytool -list -v` (here `-v` matters) shows it.

If a certificate was imported, or reimported, as a trustedcert entry -- usually in JKS, PKCS12 isn't designed for lone certs -- that never contains the chain, so `getCertificateChain` *on that entry* won't work, but IIRC `CertPathBuilder` can build a chain combining multiple trustedcert entries in one store.

If you do need a parent (chain) cert 
you don't already have, and the child specifies AIA.caIssuers, then yes using that to fetch is sensible.
I'm pretty sure there is nothing in standard Java (JRE) library that does this for you, at least so far; I don't know about BouncyCastle or anybody else.